# Jquery Issues on Mobile Device

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

Recently I got some HUGE help on here for a specific issue. I'm about 90% done with it.

I'm having an issue getting jQuery click functions to work on a mobile device.

What's strange, though, in the below code, that the top function (.cartholder > h3) works fine on a mobile device, but the rest of them do not.

(the .fa-shopping-cart is the mobile version of the .cartholder > h3, as it activates through an fa-icon--but it just doesn't work.)

```
  //Dropdown cart in header
  $('.cart-holder > h3').click(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass('cart-opened')) {
          $(this).removeClass('cart-opened').next().slideUp(300);
      } else {
          $(this).addClass('cart-opened').next().slideDown(300);
      }
  });
   //Dropdown cart in header (mobile)
   $('.fa-shopping-cart').click(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass('cart-opened')) {
          $(this).removeClass('cart-opened').next().slideUp(300);
      } else {
          $(this).addClass('cart-opened').next().slideDown(300);
      }
  });
  //Popup rating content
  $('.star-rating').each(function(){
      rate_cont = $(this).attr('title');
      $(this).append('<b class="rate_content">' + rate_cont + '</b>');
  });
  //Hamburger dropdown menu (mobile)
  $( ".cross" ).hide();
  $( ".hamburger" ).click(function() {
    $( ".sf-menu" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
      $( ".hamburger" ).hide();
      $( ".cross" ).show();
    });
  });

  $( ".cross" ).click(function() {
    $( ".sf-menu" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
      $( ".cross" ).hide();
      $( ".hamburger" ).show();
    });
  });
 //Search header (mobile)
  $( ".fa-search" ).click(function() {
    $( "#search-mobile" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
    });
  });
```

The issue shouldn't be jQuery version or touchevents, because the .cartholder > h3 DOES work on mobile.

Eager to hear back from ya :)

Comment: Have your tried setting breakpoint to see if the click function is really the problem or if the code inside it is?

Comment: Hi Patrick. What do you mean by setting breakpoint? Like media @ queries? Pardon the layperson terms.

Comment: Debug your JavaScript or make the command inside the click function perform something obvious, like an alert, if you're debugging in an actual phone

Comment: Alerts work, but not on a phone. No event takes place.

Comment: I'd try a debugger. In chrome you can click and element to see what listeners are set for each element. Check if that's ok. I remember having a problem once with an element that was over the element I added the listener to. Only the mobile layout had this problem. You can check for that too. The top element gets the click...

Comment: why you tagged this question with `jquery-mobile`? Do you have a JQM page structure?

Comment: Hi deblocker. I think... There's jquery mobile min files on my server, and I had a jquery mobile select menu source running. I imagined that's what it was. Pardon my ignorance.